# auto start script in debian

Tags: docker, debian

I want to have an auto start script for my project. I use docker and want to try a script that starts if the container start.

I tried to run update-rc and i dont have any problems but the symbolic links dont get generated. I checked it in the file explorer and with my script:

```
mkdir /var/www/$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
```

But nothing happend.
This is in my dockerfile:

```
COPY starter.sh /etc/init.d/starter.sh
RUN chmod +x /etc/init.d/starter.sh
RUN chmod 755 /etc/init.d/starter.sh
RUN update-rc.d starter.sh defaults 10
```

I dont get any error messages. Thats my problem :)

Comment: Just run your program as entrypoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below instructions in your docker file:

**COPY starter.sh /starter.sh**

**RUN chmod +x /starter.sh && chmod 0755 /starter.sh**

**ENTRYPOINT ["/starter.sh"]**

**CMD ["defaults", "10"]**

Answer (score 0):

The things in `RUN` statements are executed during image build time. They can generate files in the Docker image, but not create processes which remain running after the image build finishes (how would that even work?)

The simplest solution is probably to create an entry point which starts your service(s) and then runs any user-supplied commands.

Comment: have you an example how it can looks like? :)

Comment: Depends a lot on which precise image you are building from. [This Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/multi-service_container/) is my top Google hit for "docker debian run services".